# Rate Limiting based on URL and Path in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, managed, amazon-eks, rate-limiting

I need to implement Rate Limiting (based on URL and path) on applications deployed on Kubernetes Cluster (EKS).

I'm looking for a managed way that involves least scripting and does provide an interface through which to manage rate limits for different application.

That system should be able to work accurately at the enterprise level.

Can somebody please suggest me the path/tool/framework to follow in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 30):

`Rate-limiting` is available in NGINX [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) by using [correct annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting). Available options are:

1. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections`: number of concurrent
   connections allowed from a single IP address. A 503 error is
   returned when exceeding this limit.
2. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps`: number of requests accepted
   from a given IP each second. The burst limit is set to this limit
   multiplied by the burst multiplier, the default multiplier is 5.
   When clients exceed this limit, limit-req-status-code default: 503 is returned.
3. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm`: number of
   requests accepted from a given IP each minute. The burst limit is
   set to this limit multiplied by the burst multiplier, the default
   multiplier is 5. When clients exceed this limit,
   limit-req-status-code default: 503 is returned.
4. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-burst-multiplier`: multiplier of
   the limit rate for burst size. The default burst multiplier is 5,
   this annotation override the default multiplier. When clients exceed
   this limit, limit-req-status-code default: 503 is returned.
5. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rate-after`: initial number of
   kilobytes after which the further transmission of a response to a
   given connection will be rate limited. This feature must be used
   with [proxy-buffering enabled](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-buffering).
6. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rate`: number of kilobytes per
   second allowed to send to a given connection. The zero value
   disables rate limiting. This feature must be used with
   [proxy-buffering enabled](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-buffering).
7. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-whitelist`: client IP source ranges
   to be excluded from rate-limiting. The value is a comma separated
   list of CIDRs.

You can read more about NGINX rate limiting [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nginx-rate-limiting-in-a-nutshell-128fe9e0126c/) and for NGINX rate limiting in kubernetes [in this guide](https://medium.com/titansoft-engineering/rate-limiting-for-your-kubernetes-applications-with-nginx-ingress-2e32721f7f57).

Comment: Do you know if this can be configured based on specific path, e.g. /login/?

Comment: @riscarrott, no, currently it applies to the entire ingress where annotations are added.

Comment: Suppose I set limit-connections: 5.  It means can we only access the site from a single IP address 5 times? or is it 5 times per day?

Comment: You can use nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet to add configuration per location (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet)

Comment: Instead of using configuration-snippet, one can create multiple ingress objects and apply different annotations respectively. For example, one ingress for path / and another with rate limiting annotations, and configured for path /login